# What happen if I declare the id in CSS is duplicated to id in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

In case, I already link to CSS with the same id that I use with javascript in the same HTML page. What will happen?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My JavaScript page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
    </scrip>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="show">
        </h1>
```

In case, id, show, has declare both in javascript and css. What will happen?

Comment: As long as the ID is unique in the HTML, everything is fine. CSS and Javascript can both use this ID at their will.

Comment: ID is only for uniqueness of the element, in case of `CSS` or `JSS` you are just using the selector to apply certain `CSS` or perform some operation using `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 1):

`ID`s are a concept of HTML to mark an element in the document as unique. Thus it may be used in the whole document only once. If you are obeying this rule, you will be fine, otherwise you will get into trouble.

Javascript and CSS are two completely different technologies. You can use the HTML `ID` to target the element and apply CSS styles or work with it in some way via JS. Thus, JS and CSS do not *directly* interfere with each other.

However, you can *change* the ID with javascript or *move* it to another element, resulting in your css not applying it's rules anymore to the initial element (or applying them to another element). Also, you can apply styling via javascript, which might interfere with css.

Other than these described problems you can use the ID in both CSS and JS at will.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to use the same ID for two elements . It is a bad idea but if you are updating an already existing ID with Javascript there should not be any problem . Also if you are using two elements with same ID make a separate class for both of the elements and use ID for differentiating between them

```
<div class="one" id="diff1">
</div>
<div class="one" id="diff2">
</div>
```

Comment: _and use ID for differentiating between them_. Sounds a bit odd. How can you differentiate if they are the same?

Comment: I'm saying that if he needs to manipulate two elements , he can give same class for both elements and give different ID's hence if he want to manipulate one of them separately he can give the class and ID and if he wants to change both he can use the class.

Comment: Well, in the same sentence you say _two elements with the same ID_ so that confused me.

Answer (score 0):

Normally nothing is happen, its depending upon your javascript function. To set font color, alignment to use class instead of id via css. For show/hide some div content mean you can use id within your javascript or jquery function, eventhough you can use class is not a mistake.